# "add/show comments" should dismiss notification

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

The notification area in the top-left notifies you when there is a comment posted on your question or answer. However, if you're already on that page and click the "add / show 1 more comment" button, the notification stays there until you click it to dismiss it, even though you've already read the comment.

My suggestion would be for clicking the "add / show *n* more comments" button to denotify all watched comments that it displays.

Comment: Similarly, the responses tab in the profile will contain notifications to comments you've already read

Comment: Yes it should! Not doing so is an annoying bug; +1.